# How to stop reporting a metric with the OpenTelemetry .NET client

Tags: asp.net-core, open-telemetry

I am using OpenTelementry to capture metrics in my application.

I am wishing to capture execution timings for components of batch operations. Being batch, the activity is bursty.

I am using an observable gauge, however the .NET client is repeating the last value being captured. I can understand why, but it makes my visualisations look remarkably odd and gives the impression that the application is actively processing things that it isn't.

Disposing the `Meter` does stop measurements, but this is a fairly brutal approach - particularly if the `Meter` contains other measurements.

What is the standard approach for this? If it's of any relevance, my full stack is using Telegraf, InfluxDb2 and Grafana.

Answer (score 0):

I initially resolved this by creating a new `Meter` specifically for batch operations, and wrapping it in a scoped object which exists for the lifetime of a single batch. This approach seems to work well, however I encountered issues with using observable meters.

If disposing occurs prior to data being flushed, no metrics can be captured.

My final approach is to capture `double.MinValue` with my meter when there are no values, then just filter out values less than zero in my query.

It's a bit of a bodge, but does the trick.